# How can I save the state of an UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my app user can make some search from a UISearchBar situated in UINavigationBar. Then he can press the cell and I will pop another view controller for him. But when he presses back button in the navigation bar of this next controller, I need to pop back the UISearchDisplayController with the results of his previous search.

Basically, I just need to return to the previous state of the controller after user pressed the back button. But oddly enough I can't do it, because when I return to the initial controller, I see the Search Bar in initial state and no search results. Is there any way to deal with it?

Just to make things more specific and clear I posted some pics and code below.

Initial state:

[image]

When you type something in:

[image]

Then I just pop the new controller at the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method of my UISearchDisplayDelegate just like that:

```
[parent.navigationController pushViewController:listWordsViewController animated:YES];
```

And then I am able to go back from the listWordsViewController just by default back button. When I do so - i just see the initial state. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not supposed to happen - it should go back to the same state. can you post more of your code?

Comment: Yeap, this really was not supposed to happen. This was my bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody, who viewed this question and tried to help. I found a trouble - it was just that in -viewWillAppear some other guy, who I'm currently working with, was resetting the navigation bar. I was stupid enough not to check it.

Comment: I guess the take-home point is if you see some strange things like that happening — always look in `-viewWillAppear` and `-viewDidLoad` methods of your controller.